# Partial differential equations help

Tags: integration

Can some one please, help me to solve this exercise : Let $A$ be an open of $R^{d}$, (d>1), and $f$ a real continuous valued over $A$. Show that if for all $ v\in\mathcal{C}^{1}(A)$, $\int_{A}fv dx=0$, then $f=0$. And thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0):

Suppose that $f$ is not the identically zero function. Then there exists an $x_0\in A$, such that $f(x_0)\ne 0$. Without loss of generality assume that $f(x_0)>0$. Using the fact that $f$ is continuous at $x=x_0$ we can find a ball of radius $r$ and centered at $x_0$, i.e., $B_r(x_0)\subset A$, where $f$ is larger than $f(x_0)/2$.

Next we can find a $C^1$ function $v$ which is nonnegative in $A$, positive in $B_{r/2}(x_0)$ and vanishes outside of $B_r(x_0)$.

Then
$$
\int_A fv\,dx=\int_{B_r(x_0)} f(x)\,v(x)\,dx\ge \frac{f(x_0)}{2}\int_{B_r(x_0)} v(x)\,dx>0.
$$
Contradiction.

Comment: i get it now, thank you veru much !